# Is there a way to create an uncompressed zip from PHP?

Tags: php, compression, zip

Is there a way to create an uncompressed ZIP (level 0) from PHP?  I can't find any info in the php documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the zip tool is installed on your server, you can always use the `shell_exec()` function to execute an external command. That way you can most likely create an uncompressed zip file.

Answer (score 1):

According to php.net’s bugtracker (and [bug #41243](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41243)) this functionality is not available in the built-in zip utilities. For now you have to shell out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [exec()](http://php.net/exec) to run any command on the server, in which case it will depend on the environment (Linux, windows, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, guys!

I found a solution using pear's late Archive_Zip library. There's a bug in it causing corrupted files when using no_compression parameter. The solution found at http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=7871 solved that problem!